# -isysroot or SDKROOT problem

Tags: c, xcode, macos, history, readline

I am a newbie to libhistory, so I was looking at the sample found with readline library. Compiled it on command prompt using:

```
gcc -o ./a.out /usr/local/share/readline/histexamp.c -lreadline -L/usr/local/lib/
```

It compiles and maintains history.

Then crated a xcode project with the same file and linked against readline library it compiles fine. But when I run , it won't maintain history and crashing while enumeration of history entries. After some trials i found that -isysroot argument is the cause for this problem:

```
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

The gcc man page says isysroot is like the --sysroot option, but applies only to header files.

Why the same program behaves differently with this option?

Comment: Also see [SDKROOT, -isysroot and -syslibroot](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2005/Dec/msg00524.html) on the Apple mailing lists.

Comment: FWIW, Apple recommends you always use the latest SDK but set the deployment target to the lowest version of the OS you want to support.  There's an article [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-SW1) (that they haven't migrated yet), but the whole compatibility guide is actually a good read.

Comment: The mailing list server seems to have joined the choir invisible, but is archived at: https://web.archive.org/web/20220128114645/http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2005/Dec/msg00524.html

Answer (score 5):

-isysroot is used to define the SDK that you build with. If you build with the 10.6 SDK and then try and run on OS X 10.5 then you will probably fail. You should build with whichever SDK corresponds to the minimum required OS for your program (for maximum backward-compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

```
-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

the sysroot will overwrite the system path /usr/local etc.

In my opinion, it is a problematic way to use the SDK path by XCode. 
It will result in a non-existent path like
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/local/lib/
if you want to search in the user link -L/usr/local/lib/

I don't think it is a good idea at all to change sysroot just in order to use SDK